# Timeout is not working with istio1.4 when i am deploying below yaml file in my kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, istio

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: conductor
spec:
  hosts:
  - conductor
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: conductor  
    timeout: 1s
```

Comment: how are you checking if it is working or not?

Comment: i added delay 5 sec in other service which is called by conductor but conductor is not throwing timeout.

Comment: Can You Verify if the other service with 5s delay is accessing the `conductor` service via istio gateway (from outside of the cluster)?